# Optimization matrix using Excel 2016 (win10)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am developing a tool for solar PV design. I am trying to solve an equation where integer variables a, b, c, d,... sum to Z. The equation would be something along the lines of 19a+18b+17c+....=Z, and would want to have zero remaining. The matrix can solve for any number of solutions to the equation and then I can sort the matrix for different variables.

How would the matrix solve for multiple solutions to the same equation?

How can I optimize the matrix towards the variables a>d>g etc...?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear now, please add some sample data and desired output to help understanding it.

Comment: Total modules: 2226, Max number in series: 19, Min number in series 11. 19a+18b+17c+.....=2226. How would this be calculated for all possible integer solutions. I would like to minimize the total number of strings (sum of a + b + c...) Would it be possible to have the matrix self populate with entering a new total number of modules?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Excel's Solver Add-In. Here is the Microsoft documentation for [Excel Solver](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-Solver-9ed03c9f-7caf-4d99-bb6d-078f96d1652c).

You will need to organize your problem into variables (a,b,c...), constraints(19a+18b+17c+.....=2226), and a target goal(minimize sum of a + b + c...). Then you just let Solver know where everything is and it will find a solution. A web search for **Excel Solver Tutorial** will also turn up some helpful information.

Comment: The solver function would need to be done for each iteration and option. This is what I do currently, I am looking for code that would self populate.